# Is it possible to filter radio-waves using another radio telescope?

Tags: telescopes, radio-frequency, radio

When making an observation using a radio telescope, is it possible to filter out noise coming out from a known source by using another telescope that will focus on that noise source?
By filtering, I mean processing the observation on a computer and calculating the filtered image using the second telescope source. Assume that both of the telescopes are connected and can easily sync on time and location and exchange other information.

Comment: A better way to use multiple telescopes is to do [_inteferometry_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_interferometer).  Also, this question probably would be better suited for the [Astronomy Stackexchange site](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @SolomonSlow - well, one would not need an actual telescope to assess the known noise source, so inteferometry might not be the easiest way. But, yes, with a known noise profile one can do signal processing, the specifics of which would depend on the experiment at hand.